# When executing a batch file from python, the output is only the first line

Tags: batch-file, pycharm, psexec, sessionid

I'm using the 'qwinsta' cmd command to get the session ID of a remote computer and output it to a textfile, so I create a new batch file and write the command then I try running the batch file through python but it only returns the first line of the output. When I run the batch file by simply double-clicking it it works properly.

Using python 2.7:

```
def run_qwinsta(self, computerName):                                                 
        qwinsta_check = open("q.bat", "w")
        qwinsta_check.write('PsExec -u <username> -p <password> \\\\' + computerName + ' qwinsta' + ' > "q.txt" ')
        qwinsta_check.close()

        os.system("q.bat")
```

Expected results:

```
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE 
>services                                    0  Disc                        
 console           <username>                1  Active                      
 rdp-tcp                                 65536  Listen
```

Actual results:

```
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to avoid writing the batchfile, If you can. You can execute your batch command from `os.system()`. Also you can try using `subprocess` (documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)) and then redirecting the stdout and stderr to file.

EDIT:

`PsExec` is a good choice, but If you want another way, you can also use `ssh`.

You can run `PsExec` from `os.system()` and then write the response to text file on the remote machine. The default `PsExec` working directory is `System32` there you can find your text file.

Tested code:

```
import os

os.system('Psexec \\\\SERVER cmd.exe /c "tasklist > process_list.txt"')
```

I used tasklist, because I don't have `qwinsta` on my remote machine.

If you want to store the `PsExec` response on your machine you can use `subprocess` and then redirect the `stdout` to text file.

Tested code:

```
import subprocess

process_list = open("process_list.txt", "w")
subprocess.call(['Psexec', '\\\\SERVER', 'tasklist'], stdout=process_list)
process_list.close()
```

Actually I used Python 3.x, because I don't have Python 2.x, but it should work on both.

If this still didn't solve your problem, please provide more details to your question!

Comment: The thing is I need to use psexec, or some other way to execute commands on a remote machine